# How to drag and drop rows using only the first column of the DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to allow drag and drop in my DataGrid, but I have a lot of item renderer and item editor that makes conflicts with events when dragging.

So, I want to restrict the activation of drag and drop in the first column ?

Do you have any advice for doing that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dragStart event handler to datagrid like this:

```
protected function datagrid2_dragStartHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
   var dataGrid:DataGrid = event.currentTarget as DataGrid;
   if(event.localX>dataGrid.columns[0].width)
      event.preventDefault();
}
```